# Django/Heroku deployment problems: Won't work on Debug = False

Tags: django, debugging, heroku, path

I got my app to deploy, but pages that require an id in session are not rendering. When I set debug = true, everything works fine. Otherwise, I get error 500 message. I've tried many different solutions to no avail.

I imagine the problem is somewhere in my settings.py so I have included that below. I was also able to log the startup so that is included as well.

The main page and pages that don't get a request.session passed into them work fine, as well as functions that update the database. Only pages that require an id passed into the path are not working.

update:
I ran the logentries extension for heroku and found an error on this line:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 420, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

I still don't know what to do

```
import dj_database_url
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'wiki_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coding_dojo_final_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coding_dojo_final_project.wsgi.application'


...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '****',
    }
}

WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True

...



LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': ('%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] '
                       'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s '
                       'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly sure, but something went wrong when I compiled all my static filed. I had to...

```
+ STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
- STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```